# How to turn on tracing in Jersey WS calls, when using Guice servlet configuation

Tags: java, jersey, guice

I'm trying to turn on tracing to debug a Jersey WS call. I tried adding the init-param described [here](https://blogs.oracle.com/sandoz/entry/tracing_in_jersey), both in my Guice servlet config and in the web.xml, but can't seem to get it to work.

Here's what the Guice servlet config looks like:

```
public class GuiceServletConfig extends GuiceServletContextListener
{
private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(GuiceServletConfig.class);

public GuiceServletConfig()
{
    super();
    log.debug("creating GuiceServletConfig");
}



private static class ServletModule extends JerseyServletModule {
    private InputStream getInputStream() throws FileNotFoundException {
        File file = new File("tmp");
        String pathToTempFile = file.getAbsolutePath();
        log.debug("path to config: {}", pathToTempFile);
        String pathWithoutTmp = pathToTempFile.substring(0,
            pathToTempFile.indexOf(File.separator + "tmp"));
        StringBuilder stringBldr = new StringBuilder(pathWithoutTmp)
            .append(File.separator).append("extensions")
            .append(File.separator).append("__lib__")
            .append(File.separator).append("gelato.config.properties");
        log.debug("loading guice properties from: {}",  stringBldr.toString());
        return new FileInputStream(new File(stringBldr.toString()));
    }

    @Override
    protected void configureServlets() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        try {
            InputStream is = getInputStream();
            properties.load(is);
            Names.bindProperties(binder(), properties);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            log.error("Error binding properties: {}", ex.toString());
        }
        // Must configure at least one JAX-RS resource or the
        // server will fail to start.
        // Must configure at least one JAX-RS resource or the
        // server will fail to start.
        bind(UserResource.class);
        bind(PlayersManager.class).to(GelatoPlayersManager.class);
        bind(MessageHandler.class).to(SFSMessageHandler.class);
        Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
        params.put(PackagesResourceConfig.PROPERTY_PACKAGES, "org.buffalo.gelato.resources");
        // Route all requests through GuiceContainer
        params.put("com.sun.jersey.config.feature.Trace", "true");
        serve("/rest/*").with(GuiceContainer.class, params);
    }
}
```

and I also tried just putting it in the web.xml, but I suppose this is ignored, since I'm configured Jersey via Guice.

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service for value codes</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.feature.Trace</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>
```

Comment: Your first approach is the right one (the second one won't work as you mentioned). Do you not see `X-Jersey-Trace-*` HTTP headers in your responses?

Comment: Thanks for the response. No, I see some log messages I added to my method that gets invoked, but nothing from Jersey. I'll try to do an example without Guice in the way, and see if that maybe has something to do with it.

Comment: I traced it through in the debugger, and I see in WebApplicationImpl, it's setting isTraceEnabled to true at `this.isTraceEnabled = resourceConfig.getFeature(ResourceConfig.FEATURE_TRACE) |
                resourceConfig.getFeature(ResourceConfig.FEATURE_TRACE_PER_REQUEST);`  I'm using jersey-bundle 1.14.

Comment: I think I found out what's wrong, these traces go back to the client making the call, and I'm looking for them in a server side log file!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to see log message in your server log (your first configuration of tracing is the right one), you need to add [ResourceConfig.PROPERTY_CONTAINER_REQUEST_FILTERS](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/1.17/jersey/com/sun/jersey/api/core/ResourceConfig.html#PROPERTY_CONTAINER_REQUEST_FILTERS) and/or [ResourceConfig.PROPERTY_CONTAINER_RESPONSE_FILTERS](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/1.17/jersey/com/sun/jersey/api/core/ResourceConfig.html#PROPERTY_CONTAINER_RESPONSE_FILTERS) properties to your configuration, like:

```
params.put(ResourceConfig.PROPERTY_CONTAINER_REQUEST_FILTERS, com.sun.jersey.api.container.filter.LoggingFilter.class);
params.put(ResourceConfig.PROPERTY_CONTAINER_RESPONSE_FILTERS, com.sun.jersey.api.container.filter.LoggingFilter.class);
```

See JavaDoc of container [LoggingFilter](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/1.17/jersey/com/sun/jersey/api/container/filter/LoggingFilter.html).

Answer (score 1):

The code as posted works fine. I was looking for trace messages in the logs. I didn't realize the trace messages are sent back in the response header as described [here](https://blogs.oracle.com/sandoz/entry/tracing_in_jersey).

Comment: Right, see my answer to see how to enable logging on server.

Answer (score 0):

Same thing but with a ResourceConfig file.

In the `web.xml`:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>com.example.myapp</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
        <param-value>com.example.myapp.JerseyApplication</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>com.example.myapp</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

And in the code :

```
package com.example.myapp;

import org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class JerseyApplication extends ResourceConfig {
    public JerseyApplication() {
        System.out.println("Processing Jersey2 configuration");

        // Tracing properties (modification of the response HTTP headers)
        Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        params.put("jersey.config.server.tracing.type","ALL");
        params.put("jersey.config.server.tracing.threshold","TRACE");
        addProperties(params);

        // Scan packages for resources
        packages(true,"com.example.myapp.resources");
    }
}
```

And just add the properties as stated by [Michal Gajdos](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18267773/1033530) above if you want server's side tracing.